# bash: ./cacerts: cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, binary, redhat, execute

Despite many attempts to execute the binary file, I'm still looking for a way to execute the binary file. I have tried chmod +x pathfile -> ./filename, but I'm still getting this error **bash: ./cacerts: cannot execute binary file**. I'm using redhat linux -rhel-server-6.4-i386-dvd. Is there any software for executing binary file that I haven't installed? Thank you very much.

Comment: Additional Info:   My  File type (application/octet-stream)

Comment: what is the full output of  " file cacerts "  without the quotes of course